# jqgrid v5.2.1 with subgrid and local data CRUD operations

Tags: jqgrid, local, crud

Here is my scenario. My jqgrid v5.2.1 doesn't display any data when a page loads up. It is by design. Users will either have to enter all the data for the grid and subgrid manually or click a button to load a default data from the server in the json format via
$("#jqGrid").jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'local', data: dataResponse.groups }).trigger("reloadGrid");

Users perform CRUD operations locally until the data is right in which case a button is clicked and the grids data goes to the server via $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data').

Edit/Delete operations work fine with the default data loaded but I have a problem with adding new records.

Id's of new rows are always _empty(which is fine because the server side will generated it), but the new rows from the subgrids are not transferred to the server. The question is how to establish the relationship between the newly created rows in the main grid and associated rows in the subgrid and then transfer everything to the server for processing?

Here is the code:

```
var mainGridPrefix = "s_";

        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
            styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
            datatype: 'local',        
            editurl: 'clientArray',               
            postData: {},
            colNames: ['Id', 'Group', 'Group Description', 'Markets', 'Group sort order'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'id', key: true, hidden: true },
                { name: 'name', width: 300, sortable: false, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { maxlength: 50 } },
                { name: 'description', width: 700, sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { maxlength: 256 } },
                { name: 'market', width: 200, sortable: false, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { maxlength: 50 }  },
                { name: 'sortOrder', width: 130, sortable: false, editable: true, formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 2 } }
            ],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: 'asc',
            idPrefix: mainGridPrefix,
            subGrid: true,
            //localReader: { repeatitems: true },
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false},
            autowidth: true,               
            shrinkToFit: true,                
            loadonce: true,
            viewrecords: true,
            rowNum: 5000,
            pgbuttons: false,
            pginput: false,                
            pager: "#jqGridPager",
            caption: "Group Template",
            altRows: true,
            altclass: 'myAltRowClass',               
            beforeProcessing: function (data) {
                var rows = data.rows, l = rows.length, i, item, subgrids = {};
                for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                    item = rows[i];
                    if (item.groupItems) {
                        subgrids[item.id] = item.groupItems;
                    }
                }                   
                data.userdata  = subgrids;
            },               
            subGridRowExpanded: function (subgridDivId, rowId) {
                var $subgrid = $("<table id='" + subgridDivId + "_t'></table>"),
                    pureRowId = $.jgrid.stripPref(mainGridPrefix, rowId),
                    subgrids = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam", "userData"),
                    subgridPagerId = subgridDivId + "_p";

                $("#" + $.jgrid.jqID(subgridDivId)).append($subgrid).append('<div id=' + subgridPagerId + '></div>');

                $subgrid.jqGrid({
                    datatype: "local",
                    styleUI: 'Bootstrap',
                    data: subgrids[pureRowId],
                    editurl: 'clientArray',
                    colNames: ['Item', 'Item Description', 'Health Standard', 'Sort order', 'Statuses', 'Risks', 'Solutions', 'Budgets'],
                    colModel: [
                        { name: 'itemName', width: '200', sortable: false, editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, editoptions: { maxlength: 50 }  },
                        { name: 'itemDescription', width: '400', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { maxlength: 500 }  },
                        { name: 'healthStandard', width: '400', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { maxlength: 500 }  },
                        { name: 'itemSortOrder', width: '200', sortable: false, editable: true, formatter: 'number', formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: ',', decimalPlaces: 2 } },
                        { name: 'statuses', width: '400', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { maxlength: 500 }  },
                        { name: 'risks', width: '400', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { maxlength: 500 } },
                        { name: 'solutions', width: '400', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { maxlength: 500 } },
                        { name: 'budgets', width: '400', sortable: false, editable: true, editoptions: { maxlength: 100 } }
                    ],
                    //rownumbers: true,
                    rowNum: 5000,
                    autoencode: true,
                    autowidth: true,
                    pgbuttons: false,
                    viewrecords: true,
                    pginput: false,
                    jsonReader: { repeatitems: false, id: "groupId" },
                    gridview: true,
                    altRows: true,
                    altclass: 'myAltRowClass',
                    idPrefix: rowId + "_",
                    pager: "#" + subgridPagerId
                });

                $subgrid.jqGrid('navGrid', "#" + subgridPagerId, { edit: true, add: false, del: true, search: true, refresh: false, view: false  }, // options
                    { closeAfterEdit: true }, // edit options  //recreateForm: true
                    { closeAfterAdd: true },  // add options
                    {},   //del options
                    {}  // search options
                );
            }               
        });

        $('#jqGrid').navGrid('#jqGridPager', { edit: true, add: false, del: true, search: true, refresh: false, view: false }, // options
            // options for Edit Dialog
            {                   
                editCaption: "Edit Group",                   
                beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').center();
                },                    
                bottominfo: "<br/>",
                recreateForm: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterEdit: true                    
            },
            // options for Add Dialog
            {

                //url:'clientArray',
                addCaption: "Add Group",                   
                beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').center();
                },                   
                bottominfo: "<br/>",
                recreateForm: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterAdd: true                    
            },  
            // options for Delete Dailog
            {
                caption: "Delete Group",
                beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').center();
                },
                msg: "Are you sure you want to delete?",
                recreateForm: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterDelete: true                    
            },
            // options for Search Dailog
            {
                caption: "Search Group",
                beforeShowForm: function (form) {
                    form.closest('.ui-jqdialog').center();
                },                   
                recreateForm: true,
                closeOnEscape: true,
                closeAfterDelete: true
            }
        );
```

Comment: The key row of main grid is id, but which field of the subgrid connects to the main id field?

Comment: Adding rows in your code is disabled - how the users add records in both grid and subgrid? or this is a task which should work in sync

Comment: I forgot to enable add functionality before posted here. Assuming add is set to true how to link main grid and subgrid so users can add rows and post to the server?

Answer (score 0):

There was a small bug in the  form editing which is fixed now. Thank you for help us to find them.

Now to the problem.

When you add data in main grid it is natural  to add a unique id of every row. Since of the bug instead of inserting a row  with the Guriddo id Generator there was a wrong insertion with id = s_empty. This causes every inserted row in main grid to have same id, which is not correct.

The fix is published in GitHub and you can try it.

We have updated your demo in order to insert correct the data in the subgrid. The only small addition is in afterSubmit event in add mode, where the needed item is created.

Hope this will solve the problem

Here is the [demo with the fixed version](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/hierarchy/subgrid_edit/)

**Edited**

At server you can analyze the id column if contain string 'jqg', which will point you that this is a new row. The corresponding id for the subgrid is  in userData module which will connect the main grid id with the subgrid data

**EDIT 2**

One possible solution to what you want to achieve is to get the main data and the to get the subgrid data using userData property. After this make a loop to main data and update it like this

```
var maindata =  $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data');
var subgrids = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'userData');

for(var i= 0;i < maindata.length;i++) {
    var key = maindata[i].id;
    if(subgrids.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
        if(!maindata[i].hasOwnProperty(groupItems) ) {
            maindata[i].groupItems = [];
        }
        maindata[i].groupItems = subgrids[key];
    }
}
```

The code is not tested, but I think you got the idea.

The other way is to update the groupitems on every CRUD of subgrid, which I think is not so difficult to achieve.

Comment: Thank you Tony for your response. The your fix soled the _empty id problem but it didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Thank you Tony for your response. Your fix solved the _empty id problem but it didn't solve my problem. Please do the following in the your demo and you'll see what I mean. Start your demo page and once your data (maindata) is loaded delete all rows from both grids. Your grid and subgrid will be completely empty. Then add one row to the main grid and one row to the subgrid. Now try to read the grids data via var testdata = $("#jqGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'data') you'll see that subgrid data is not there. I'm missing groupItems binding in the main grid. Your help is appreciated.

Comment: My goal is to start from the totally empty grids and once a users adds rows to grids read the data in BOTH grids and send it to the server.

Comment: The code you posted is wrong and it never will contain the new grouped items in the data of the main grid. Just try with your code to edit/add/delete some existing row in the subgrid and your data of main grid is not changed. You have two options - either to rebuild the data of the maingrid when it is posted or to update it in any operation of the grid and subgrid.

Comment: Thank you Tony. With a little change of your code everything works as expected now.